# I have a problem with my number format in php

Tags: php, html, session-variables, number-formatting

I want to allow my users to store values in the `$_SESSION` variable, I have this code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>
            <td>฿<?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] *
                    $values["item_price"], 7); ?></td>
            <td><a href="atcform.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>
            "><span class="remove-span">Remove</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
        <td align="right">$<?php echo number_format($total, 7); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

When I run it it says:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Users\auser\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\Website1\atcform.php on line 76 and line 72

Those two lines are where the `number_format`s are, I would like to eliminate these errors, do tell me if you need to see more code.

Here's a current picture:
[image: screenshot]

Thank you!

Comment: What does a `var_dump($values);` show? Those values are likely not what you think they are or should be.

Comment: To go in the same direction as everybody, maybe your price contains the currency.

Comment: I don't quite understand, another thing I've added a screenshot for clarification

Comment: Even if a solution is given you can check with the 4 options of number_format. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of the values inside of `number_format()` are not of a numerical type.

Try casting the numerical values in `floatval()`:

```
number_format(floatval($values["item_quantity"]) * floatval($values["item_price"]), 7);
```

Or even better, ensure that the values are floats before doing any numerical operation on them by re-assigning them at the beginning of the loop.

```
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) { 
    $values["item_quantity"] = floatval($values["item_quantity"]);
    $values["item_price"] = floatval($values["item_price"]);
....
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem, now all the errors are gone and the next step is to configure the decimal values so they can be multiplied